# What caused nvme QID timeout?

Tags: disk, nvme

Sometimes I see the nvme error logs:

```
nvme nvme1: I/O 332 QID 1 timeout, aborting
nvme nvme1: Abort status: 0x0
nvme nvme1: I/O 332 QID 1 timeout, reset controller
nvme nvme1: I/O 0 QID 0 timeout, reset controller
```

Does that mean some command from the host controller to device(SSD) timeout?

basically, it is a storage device problem?

Will it auto-retry then userspace still get the correct result?